# Environment Variables don't work in a nested JS file (React)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables

I'm trying to use environment variables in create-react-app.

I've prefixed all of the variables in my .env file with REACT_APP_ and installed/required dotenv.

However, I'm suspecting that the reason why my .env values aren't being read is because the script in which I'm calling them from isn't in the root folder where my .env file is located.

There's a quick overview of my project structure below

`ROOT:
    .env
    VIEWS (folder):
        view.js`

I'm trying to access the .env variables in view.js by calling `process.env.REACT_APP_MYVAR` but it either doesn't return a value or returns something that isn't a string (which is the error my API is throwing, but it could be because that call is returning `undefined`)

Is this a known issue or is there any way I can fix this? I could just take the script out of that folder and put it in the root of my app but I'd rather keep the structuring of the app consistent

Comment: Which build tool you are using right now? "create-react-app" "webpack" "parcel" "gulp" "grunt" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to "install/require" dotenv. If you are using create-react-app, this functionality is available with no additional install required.

You indicate that `.env` is in your root, but I suspect it may not actually be in your root. From your description, it sounds like you have it in your root **source** folder, but the `.env` file belongs in the root directory of your app (i.e. the same directory as your `package.json` file).

Here's a CodeSandbox (using create-react-app) that demonstrates using an environment variable in a nested file:

[image: Edit jnqv2v986w]

The contents of this sandbox includes:

`.env` (in the same directory as your `package.json` file)

```
REACT_APP_MYVAR=Here is my value for REACT_APP_MYVAR
```

`src/index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import View from "./views/View";
function App() {
  return <View />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

`src/views/View.js`

```
import React from "react";
const View = () => {
  return <div>My Var: {process.env.REACT_APP_MYVAR}</div>;
};
export default View;
```

The result that gets rendered is:

> My Var: Here is my value for REACT_APP_MYVAR

The environment variable can be used in any of the js source files regardless of level of nesting.

If this doesn't help with your problem, please show the exact contents of your `.env` and `view.js`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Ryan, yeah you're right. Stupid, tired me saw "build failed" in CI and I had a complete panic attack. It was in the src folder, somehow I moved it into there

Answer (score 0):

remove `dotenv`. Here is my `git-repo` for accessing REACT_APP_KEY. tell me if this solves your problem.

[git-repo](https://github.com/Rajuchoudhary/react-app-key)

Answer (score 0):

Change `.env` to `.env.development.local`

Actually `.env` also work but if you have other `.env.*` file it will override `.env`,

`.env` is least priority in **create-react-app**

if you run project with `npm start` this file `.env.development.local` will override other `env` files

priority goes like this, form left to right

`npm start: .env.development.local, .env.development, .env.local, .env`